# Writing Midi File From Scratch Using Hexadecimal

Tags: encoding, format, hex, sublimetext, midi

I am trying to write a midi file from scratch. It will play a C major arpeggio of 3 crotchets. I've been using sublime text to save using hex encoding. The result I then import into logic (after changing the extension to .mid). So far this has been unsuccessful, and logic simply does nothing.

I gained most of my information from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xsgf.png) and have written the following:

> 4d 54 68 64 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 01 00 18 4d 54 72 6b 00 00 00 1e 80
>   18 81 3c 7f 80 00 91 3c 00 80 18 81 40 7f 80 00 91 40 00 80 18 81 43
>   7f 80 00 91 43 00

Here is a breakdown of each byte, it's in note form but summarises my understanding of the file format: 
[image: Byte breakdown for MIDI file]

Could anybody point out why this isn't loading the correct result into Logic. Have I misunderstood the file format itself or is the problem deeper in the encoding.
**UPDATE: here is the final, corrected hexadecimal...**

> 4d 54 68 64 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 01 00 18 4d 54 72 6b 00 00 00 22 80
>   18 91 3c 7f 80 00 81 3c 00 80 18 91 40 7f 80 00 81 40 00 80 18 91 43
>   7f 80 00 81 43 00 00 ff 2f 00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The track lacks the end-of-track meta event (type 2F, length 0). So add the bytes `00 FF 2F 00`, and adjust the track size accordingly.

The track contains six MIDI messages. All six are note-off messages, so there are not any actual notes.

`8x` is a note-off message.
`9x` is a note-on message, but a velocity of 0 actually specifies a note-off. (This is an optimization that is helpful when using running status.)